# R- Dataframe not storing tables/data

Tags: r

I have the following code to edit my the date and time in my data. I'm trying to save the results into df11 and df22 but when I double click on df11 and df22 in the environment (top right corner of RStudio) to view the data frames, they don't show me the updated results. It shows me the same tables/data that is in df1 and df2 as if they were never modified.

```
df1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L), 
                      Full.Name = c( "John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown", "Chloe Brown", "John Smith" ), 
                      Info = c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 13L), DateTime = c("1/2/21 00:00", "1/5/21 12:00", "1/1/21 1:31", "1/5/21 3:34", "5/9/21 5:33", "5/8/21 3:39", "12/12/21 2:30", "12/11/21 9:21"), 
                      Temp = c("100", "103", "104", "103", "101", "102", "103", "105"), 
 
                      misc = c("(null)", "no", "(null)", "(null)", "(null)","(null)", "(null)", "(null)" 
                                    )), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                      Full.Name = c("John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown"), 
                      DOB = c("1/1/90", "1/10/90", "1/2/90", "2/20/80", "2/2/80", "12/2/80"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), EncounterDate = c("1/1/21", "1/2/21", "1/1/21", "1/6/21", "5/7/21", "5/8/21"), 
                      Type = c("Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), 
                      responses = c("(null)", "no", 
                                    "yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), 
                      
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -6L))
loadedNamespaces()
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

df11 <- 
df1 %>% 
  separate(DateTime, c("Date", "Time"), sep=" ") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_datetime(mdy(Date))) %>% 
  select(-Time) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df22 <-
df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), mdy)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), as_datetime)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Comment: That's because you are never modifying `df1` or `df2`. The dplyr functions return new data.frames, they do not update in place. Your code saves the new values as `df11` and `df22`.

Comment: There's some confusion here. The user says that they are clicking on df11 and df22, which should contain the modified results, but states that they look the same as df1 and df2.